# undefined local variable or method 'request' - in controller helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

We have been seeing an increasing number of errors with the same call sight:

`NameError: undefined local variable or method 'request' for :false:Symbol`

They are all raising from an authentication helper located in `lib`. This method runs successfully 99% of the time (we know because it logs you in without issue). However, for a very small number of requests the `request` object can't be found, as shown in the error message.

We have been seeing this for a variety of user agents. For what it's worth, `ApplicationController` includes (via `include`) the helper in question.

Is there any common debugging techniques or known issues where `request` can be missing during a Rails request? If it helps, the same occurs for `cookies`.

The relevant bits of code:

```
# lib/authenticated_system.rb
module AuthenticatedSystem
  def logged_in?
    current_user != :false
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= login_via_cookie || login_via_url || :false
    @current_user
  end

  def login_via_cookie
    Rails.logger.info "IP: #{request.ip}" # example of accessing request
    if token = cookies[:web_token]
      User.find_by(auth_token: token)
    end
  end

  def login_via_url
    # return User or nil
  end
end

# app/controllers//foo_controller.rb
class FooController < ApplicationController
  include Alerting

  def show
    log_alert(current_user)
  end
end

# lib/alerting.rb
module Alerting
  def log_alert(user)
    Rails.logger.info "User: #{user.id}" # example of accessing user
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that it's trying to run the method `request` on a symbol... so some method that was to return an object that responds to `request` instead is returning `:false`.  Check the code for a call like `xxx.request` and then examine the `xxx` method to see under what circumstances it would return `:false`

Comment: Can you post, how calling lib library any async calls or jobs ?

Comment: Do you have any background jobs that use the method that calls the `request` or the `cookies` method?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I've added the relevant code. I'm not setting `request` to anything, or `self`, but I do mention `:false` in some of the code. Perhaps that isn't behaving the way I'm expecting it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code isn't correct...

```
@current_user ||= login_via_cookie || login_via_url || :false
```

It's setting @current_user to the symbol `:false`

Better to set it to the object `false` or still better, let it default to `nil`

```
@current_user ||= (login_via_cookie || login_via_url)
```

and change the `logged_in?` to...

```
def logged_in?
  !!current_user
end
```

At some point in one of your lib modules I suspect you're calling `current_user.request` which is causing the problem.

Comment: We were setting it to `:false` so we could circumvent repeated database calls to get the user. As in, check if `@current_user != :false`. But a better approach is to use `defined?(@current_user)`, which is what we've adopted. Thanks for the guidance!